# How can I do an AND search from a dictionary, sending a list of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a big json file containing items in the following format:

```
{"Disease":["Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae\r","Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor\r","Cholera, unspecified\r","Typhoid fever, unspecified\r","Typhoid meningitis\r","Typhoid fever with heart involvement\r","Typhoid pneumonia\r","Typhoid arthritis\r","Typhoid osteomyelitis\r","Typhoid fever with other complications\r","Paratyphoid fever A\r","Paratyphoid fever B\r","Paratyphoid fever C\r","Paratyphoid fever, unspecified\r","Salmonella enteritis\r","Salmonella sepsis\r","Localized salmonella infection, unspecified\r"],"Code":["A000","A001","A009","A0100"]}
```

My django program will be sending a list of values to a script which needs to do an AND search (meaning it will return a value from a dictionary, if all the search strings are substrings of a value in Disease in the json). It will need to return multiple values as a json which is sent to javascript and rendered.

Currently I am able to do an OR search with the following code:

```
slist = ['myocardial', 'infarction']

def advanced_icd(request, slist):
    import json
    from myappointments.settings import PROJECT_ROOT
    url = PROJECT_ROOT + '/appointments/static/clinic/db/icd10.json'
    import pandas as pd
    db = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=url)
    codedb = db.to_dict()
    result_Disease = []
    result_Code = []
    for (key, Disease), (key1, Code) in zip(codedb['Disease'].items(), codedb['Code'].items()):
        for searchstr in slist:
            searchstr = searchstr.lower()                
            if searchstr in Disease.lower():
                print("Found a disease at key:%s Disease:%s Code:%s" %
                      (key, Disease, Code))
                result_Disease.append(Disease)
                result_Code.append(Code)   
    outp = json.dumps(
        {'Disease': result_Disease, 'Code': result_Code})
    print(outp)

advanced_icd("", slist)

Output:
Code:D735sease at key:2844 Disease:Infarction of spleen
Code:G43501ase at key:4777 Disease:Persistent migraine aura without cerebral infarction, not intractable, with status migrainosus
```

Comment: SQL databases are not bit buckets, they are tools for _querying_ data - and so are dedicated full-text search engines too... Using one or the other might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing `db` is a `pandas.DataFrame` instance, you can use the
`DataFrame.loc` attribute to select a subset of its rows using a sequence of
bools. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
print(df.loc[[True, True, False, False, True]])
```

Which gives this output:

```
  var
0   a
1   b
4   e
```

In other words, rows corresponding to `True` got selected.

Applying this to your problem, suppose you had a list of search terms like so:

```
slist = ['late', 'acute', 'deep']
```

You would define a pair of helper functions which would tell you, for a given
disease, whether it matches these search terms:

```
cond_or = lambda disease: any(s.lower() in disease.lower() for s in slist)
cond_and = lambda disease: all(s.lower() in disease.lower() for s in slist)
```

Then all that's left to do is apply one of these functions to the `Disease`
column and using using the result to select matching rows:

```
>>> matching_diseases = db.loc[db.Disease.map(cond_and)]
>>> matching_diseases
                                             Disease    Code
6847   Acute embolism and thrombosis of other specifi...  I82.493
7708   Acute embolism and thrombosis of unspecified d...  I82.4Z3
21460  Acute embolism and thrombosis of unspecified d...  I82.4Y3
33825  Acute embolism and thrombosis of unspecified d...  I82.403
42904  Acute embolism and thrombosis of deep veins of...  I82.623
```

Since `matching_diseases` is also a `DataFrame`, you can simply select its
columns to get sequences corresponding to codes or diseases:

```
result_Disease = matching_diseases['Disease']
result_Code = matching_diseases['Code']
```

Comment: So how can I return the list of values from the dictionary, which satisfied the AND search?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part of your question. Since you're using pandas, you could actually leverage its machinery to do this more easily. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Droidzone, did my updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: I tried an alternate longer term solution and converted my data to sql